# retrofit shows response in logs but fragment comes out blank

Tags: json, listview, retrofit2

I've tried almost all the solutions but still can't figure out the problem.Response is being shown in logs but it still shows a blank fragment.Maybe am not parsing it correctly?How do I do that? 
JSON response:

```
[
  {
    "place_id": "1",
    "stop_id": "0",
    "place_name": "Udon House",
    "category": "food",
    "rating": "3",
    "latitude": "31.5076701",
    "longitude": "74.3544522",
    "description": "a trip to the landa (Flea market of Lahore), tea time and chess with neighbors and a date at Udon House with Nida. I really need that heart to heart session with her. Too much to be unloaded off the chest and  Udon House is the perfect place to do that. At least for us.",
    "db_image": "images/udonHouse.jpg"
  },
  {
    "place_id": "5",
    "stop_id": "0",
    "place_name": "Lahore Meuseum",
    "category": "attractions",
    "rating": "4",
    "latitude": "31.5681556",
    "longitude": "74.3061492",
    "description": "want to discover histroy?",
    "db_image": "images/badshahi.jpg"
  },
  {
    "place_id": "4",
    "stop_id": "0",
    "place_name": "Pearl Continental ",
    "category": "hotels",
    "rating": "2",
    "latitude": "31.552531",
    "longitude": "74.3359265",
    "description": "hotel,pool and everything you need.",
    "db_image": "images/1.jpg"
  },
  {
    "place_id": "6",
    "stop_id": "0",
    "place_name": "Shalimar Gardens",
    "category": "attractions",
    "rating": "2",
    "latitude": "31.586937",
    "longitude": "74.3780747",
    "description": "The city of Lahore is often referred to as the City of Gardens for the reason that many a beautiful garden of ancient and modern times and architecture are found all over the city. Successive Mogul emperors constructed a number of gardens to add to the beauty of Lahore – a city they loved the most.",
    "db_image": "images/1.jpg"
  },
  {
    "place_id": "2",
    "stop_id": "0",
    "place_name": "Casa Biance",
    "category": "food",
    "rating": "4",
    "latitude": "31.5108486",
    "longitude": "74.3459973",
    "description": "A varity of seafood and vegetable fried in a homemade tempura batter and served with tartar sauce",
    "db_image": "images/e1c6e8964483782e30ee09b92191c544.jpg"
  },
  {
    "place_id": "3",
    "stop_id": "0",
    "place_name": "Pizza hut",
    "category": "food",
    "rating": "5",
    "latitude": "31.4622413",
    "longitude": "74.2732879",
    "description": "Order pizza online for fast pizza delivery or drop by for carryout. You may also contact Pizza Hut and find out about our catering services for your next big event.",
    "db_image": "images/pizza2lahore.jpg"
  }
]
```

interface:

```
public interface fav_interface {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("getFavorites.php")
    Call<List<FavoritesModel>> getFavs(@Field("user_id") int user_id);
}
```

model:

```
public class FavoritesModel {

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("place_id")
    int  place_id;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("place_name")
    String Place_name;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("latitude")
    Double latitude;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("longitude")
    Double logitude;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("category")
    String category;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName( "description")
    String description;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("db_image")
    String db_image;

    FavoritesModel(int place_id, String place_name, String img, String des){
        this.place_id = place_id;
        this.Place_name = place_name;
        this.db_image = img;
        this.description = des;
    }
....
```

adapter:

```
public class favAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<favAdapter.ViewHolder> {
  place_details place_details;

    Constants constant;
    private Context context;
    private List<FavoritesModel> places_list;
    FavoritesModel favoritesModel;


    public favAdapter(Context context, List<FavoritesModel> places) {
        this.context = context;
        this.places_list = places;

    }


    @Override
    public favAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_item, viewGroup, false);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(favAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        places_list.get(position);

        holder.place_name.setText(places_list.get(position).getPlace_name());

        //.placeholder(R.color.colorAccent)
        Glide.with(context).load(constant.BASE_URL + places_list.get(position).getPlace_name()).into(holder.place_image);


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (places_list != null) {
            return places_list.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private static final String TAG = "position";
        private TextView place_name, place_category;
        ImageView place_image, Bucket, like;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            place_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.place_name);
            place_image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.place_image);


            place_image.setOnClickListener(this);
            place_name.setOnClickListener(this);


        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.place_name: {
....
}
```

Comment: Hi , tried doing a dry run in my sample code there seems to be no issue with Entity or parsing . Try debugging your code . Let me know if you want my sample code .

Answer (score 1):

You can receive response as JsonElement and deserialize it to your List by any method.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("getFavorites.php")
    Call<JsonElement> getFavs(@Field("user_id") int user_id);
```

Response:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                JsonElement jsonElement = response.body();
                JsonObject objectWhichYouNeed = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
                //do whatever you want with Json Object. Deserialize it, get values by keys, get as String etc.
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(response.message());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("Failed");
        }
    });
```

Comment: I want to get a list of objects.e.g  Call<List<JsonElement>>

Comment: @NukhbaArshad There is no way to do as you want. JsonElement - completely full result which you can parse to list or whatever you want. 
It can be json array which you will parse to your list object.

Comment: This is not the right way of doing it , we get List of object directly .